# Does boto3 support (or have plan to support) Aurora postgresql-compatible db instance creation?

Tags: boto3, amazon-aurora

Looking at all documentation I couldn't find if boto3 supports creating Aurora postgresql-compatible DB instance - if not is there any plan for that and could we have any other option to create such postgresql compatible (like with aws cli if possible)?

Comment: "creating Aurora postgresql-compatible DB instance" : please clarify, do you want to create a RDS instance? Or you want to create a EC2 instance with postgresql inside ? Or ?

Comment: @mootmoot it's about this https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/announcing-open-preview-of-amazon-aurora-with-postgresql-compatibility/, the newly supported Aurora instance (of course it's in RDS) compatible with Postgresql

Comment: Well, it seems you need to sign up the preview release, which is NOT inside the AWS control panel, perhaps the preview only available for specific region.

Comment: @mootmoot I've already got the preview, and I can launch it from RDS web console, for sure. The question is whether boto3 (or AWS CLI) already supports this new Engine (for automation), from their docs seems they still have only 1 Aurora engine (which implies the MySQL-compatible one)?

Comment: You can ask the question in github. 
https://github.com/boto/boto3